# Option Base 1 Returning Array with Base 0

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I have some code that parses the DataBodyRange of a ListObject  to variable new_arr with type Variant.  I have set Option Base 1 at the start of the module however when I look at the created array I  end up with a 0 based array.  Im sure I missing something simple

```
If isExcel(FSOFile) Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FSOFile)
            psheet = isProposal(wb)
            If psheet > 0 Then
                new_arr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposals").ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
                thisdata = wb.Sheets(psheet).Range("B11:AD100").Value
                pData = proposalData(wb.Sheets(psheet), new_arr)
            End If
        wb.Close
    End If
```

Comment: new_arr should be base 1. Are you sure the listobject has data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Microsoft documentation, it applies to arrays not objects:

> Used at the module level to declare the default lower bound for array
>   subscripts.

[See this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-base-statement):

[and this wonderful explanation](https://superuser.com/questions/988321/which-excel-objects-are-zero-based-and-which-are-one-based) about the difference

Comment: thanks Ricardo  the links helped get this clear in my mind